# Не отображаются картинки в приложении Xcode 10b4 iOS 12b2

Tags: ios, xcode

После обновления до беты macOS Mojave, обновления XCode до версии 10.0 beta 4, обновления проекта до Swift 4.2, и тестового устройства (iPad Pro первого поколения) до iOS 12 beta 2, в проекте перестали отображаться почти все картинки из Assets.xcassets, за исключением двух-трёх. Консоль говорит следующее:

```
[framework] CoreUI: Encoded Deepmap blob version 1128416075 does not match with current version 4
[framework] CoreUI: Unable to decompress stream for CSI image block data. 'deepmap-lzfse'
error in connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted
```

Пробовал импортировать все картинки непосредственно драг-н-дропом из папки Assets.xcassets в очищенный Assets.xcassets нового проекта. Результата ноль, работающих картинок стало только меньше.

Google не знаком с этой ошибкой. Проблема также повторяется на iPhone SE на той же версии iOS.

Ссылка на тестовый проект, в котором при том же железе и софте проблема повторяется:

https://dropmefiles.com/dfQ40

UPD: Добавление картинок размера x2 и x3 не решило проблему.

UPD 2: Обновился до Xcode 10 beta 5, попробовал скомпилировать на другой машине (MacBook Pro mid 2014), не помогло.

UPD 3: На симуляторе картинки работают корректно. Ошибка воспроизводится только на настоящем устройстве.

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: так там нет в Assests картинок размеров Retina х2 х3

Comment: @FreeGor, Насколько я помню, в XCode 9 если не существовало картинки под x3, он брал картинку x2. Аналогично с x2. Если Apple выпилили это, стоило хотя бы предупредить. Я голову сломал.

Comment: @FreeGor, Увы, добавление картинок для x2 и x3 не решило проблему.

Comment: у вас проблема и с добавлением UIImageView на ViewController view, добавляют с помощью view.addSubview(imageView) и определяют констрейнты,или на худой случай frame для imageView. Где вы вообще такой код нашли?

Comment: @FreeGor, если посмотреть в runtime-иерархию, то ImageView принимает размер изображения. Проверьте.

Comment: вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: @FreeGor, если вы сделали что-то, после чего проблема исчезла, отправляйте ответ.

Comment: назначьте imageView.backgroundColor = .white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновление до iOS 12 beta 5 решило проблему